# Navigating an excel document using excel links

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'd like to be able to click on some text in a cell that automatically moves the insertion point to a specified cell or row.

So ideally I could have a cell (or some text in a cell) say: ["see row 199"], and when I click on it, it moves me to row 199.

How do I do this in excel?

Comment: Create a hyperlink but instead of linking to a webpage, link to the desired cell. [See Source](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/exceltips/qt/90103goto.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Insert > Hyperlink, then select 'Place in This Document' and enter the cell reference you want to link to.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This worked well, but is there a way I can have the insertion point at the top of my screen? Its highlighting my cell and navigates to it, but its towards the bottom of my screen.

Comment: @Nebur Unfortunately I don't think there is a simple solution using just hyperlinks, but it *might* be possible using a macro

Comment: This is easy with VBA: "Range("A1").Show"  The downside is that you'd _also_ have to code the hyperlink functionality.